# Is "To get you to know me better" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is "To get you to know me better" grammatically correct? It is supposed to be an informal letter.

Comment: Yep!  It's not a complete sentence, though.  Is it part of a larger sentence, or is it in a context where it would make sense by itself?

Comment: I think we need to ask what you intend by this.  If it's something like:  "I've sent you these pictures and some of my writing to get you to know me better." then it works but it's not really idiomatic.  (I'd say, instead, "so you can know me better" or simply "so you can get to know me better" or "to help you get to know me better")

Comment: This will always remind me of Dickens, "Come in, and know me better, man!"

Answer (score 2):

> *to get you to know me better*

is not, as pointed out, a complete sentence. 
It consists of one infinitive clause

- .. *(for you) to know me better*

as object complement to another infinitive clause (with causative *get*)

- *(for `X`) to get you [(for you) to know me better]*

Their subjects, *you* in the lower clause and *`X`* in the upper one, got deleted with the complementizers,
leaving only the bare subjectless infinitives.  So, as far as it goes, it's a correct phrase.

But it's not correct as a sentence, because infinitives can't form sentences.
A sentence has to have a main verb that is inflected in the present or past tense.
And there are lots of sentences where *to get you to know me better* would not work.

Executive Summary: Use complete sentences when asking questions and when giving examples.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds awkward and should be reworded to more accurately fit the context of the particular statement.

For example, to use a previous contributor's example, "I've sent you these pictures and some of my writing to get you to know me better," you don't want the person to know *you* better, you want them to know your pictures and writing better.

It would be better to say something like, "I've sent you these pictures and some of my writing so you can get a better idea of my skills."

Sometimes, rather than struggling over individual words or phrases, it is better to cross everything out and start over.  Think about the message you are really trying to put across, and go fro there.